# Attach view of content by author only to the user page

Tags: views, 9

I am using the [EVA: Entity Views Attachment](https://www.drupal.org/project/eva) module to create a view of content by author, to attach it to each author's user page.  So, for example, when viewing /user/1, I will see a list of all the content created by user #1.

I've been able to do this successfully, but too successfully: Not only does this list show up on the author's user page, but it also shows up on every single piece of content that user has written.
Obviously, I don't want it to show up there.

How can I fix this, so that it only shows up on the user page?

These are my settings.

- Entiti content settings

  - Entity type: User
  - Bundles: User
  - Arguments: id
- Contextual filters
- Content: Author UID

  - When the filter value is not available

    - Provide a default value: *Type: User ID* from route context

I'm working with Drupal 9, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used this module, but according to the project page:

> The placement of the view in the entity's content can be reordered on
> the "Field Display" administration page for that entity, like other
> fields added using the Field UI module.

So you should be able to configure this at **Manage Display** for users: `/admin/config/people/accounts/display`.  You can customize the display separately for `Default` and `Compact`, and you can create more view modes (different display configurations) as necessary.

Another way to do what you're doing (attach a view to users only on the user page) would be to use Layout Builder, which is included standard with Drupal.

1. Make a view that shows the user's content with contextual filters in a block.
2. Enable Layout Builder module.
3. On `/admin/config/people/accounts/display`, check **Use Layout Builder**, open Layout Builder, and then add the block.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not very familiar with Layout Builder, I've just enabled it, and checked the "Use Layout Builder"... but how do I open "Layout Builder"?  I'm not finding where to do that.

Comment: Oh, never mind, I see the "Manage Layout" button.  Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm, so, update.  Still can't get it to work with Layouts.  If I just make my view a regular block, and then add it to the user's page with Layouts... nothing shows up.  And if I use Eva, then it shows up in both the User page and each Node page.  It's like I can't win.

Comment: @JamesDunn For the block shown with Layout Builder, if nothing appears, you probably have the contextual filter configured wrong.  To test this, add a **Text area** block to the **No results behavior** area on the view's admin screen, or change *Provide default value* in the contextual filter options to *User ID from logged in user* and test while logged in.

Comment: For EVA, you should see the EVA view on the field management screen (`/admin/config/people/accounts/display`) as well as within Layout Builder when you have that enabled, so you should be able to modify where it is shown that way.

Comment: Thanks Patrick!  Turns out I edited the layout on the wrong view mode this whole time.  I edited the correct one and now it works.  :P  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers you could (for  the single user page) provide a single twig template in your theme and then exclude the field from rendering (with the "without" twig filter function).

https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/twig-in-drupal/filters-modifying-variables-in-twig-templates

Comment: Since the OP is using a view and the _EVA: Entity Views Attachment_ module, in which way would a template file help him? Keep in mind that link-only answers aren't considered answers.

Comment: As far as I understand the question, the OP want's that the field is getting rendered only at one single page. The EVA view is rendered as a field in node display. So the OP could define a twig template only for the single page the EVA field is wishing to be displayed in.